# How to pass a struct type as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, templates

I’m trying to add a parameter to a function and I need the new parameter to be a struct type.

Here is the function I want to change, from [dyld_decache.cpp](https://github.com/kennytm/Miscellaneous/blob/master/dyld_decache.cpp)

```
void prepare_patch_objc_methods(uint32_t method_vmaddr, uint32_t override_vmaddr);
```

I changed it like this:

```
template <typename T>
void prepare_patch_objc_methods(typename T::type, uint32_t list_vmaddr, uint32_t override_vmaddr);
```

Inside the implementation of `prepare_patch_objc_methods`, I changed all occurrences of `method_t` to `T` and it compiles fine.

The `method_t` struct is defined like this:

```
struct method_t {
    uint32_t name;
    uint32_t types;
    uint32_t imp;
};
```

Now, how do I pass a struct type when calling this function?

I tried to do this

```
this->prepare_patch_objc_methods(method_t, class_data->baseMethods, class_obj->data + offsetof(class_ro_t, baseMethods));
```

but I get the following error: `'method_t' does not refer to a value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you dont need to pass an object of your struct type into the function (you just need to pass a type itself), so the correct function declaration would be

```
template <typename T>
void prepare_patch_objc_methods(uint32_t list_vmaddr, uint32_t override_vmaddr);
```

Now to pass a struct type to a function you call it like this

```
this->prepare_patch_objc_methods<method_t>(class_data->baseMethods, class_obj->data + offsetof(class_ro_t, baseMethods));
```

In case you actually need to pass an object of a parameter type, you do something like this

```
template <typename T>
    void prepare_patch_objc_methods(const T &object, uint32_t list_vmaddr, uint32_t override_vmaddr);
```

Then you call it like this

```
method_t obj;
this->prepare_patch_objc_methods<method_t>(obj, class_data->baseMethods, class_obj->data + offsetof(class_ro_t, baseMethods));
```

or simply like this

```
this->prepare_patch_objc_methods(obj, class_data->baseMethods, class_obj->data + offsetof(class_ro_t, baseMethods));
```

Here you dont necessarily need to specify the type explicitly because the compiler can deduce it from the object you are passing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an actual object of that type, not the type itself, as the parameter:

```
method_t m;

prepare_patch_objc_methods(m, class_data->baseMethods, /* ... */);
```

Edit: in case this isn't clear: you can't pass a type (such as `method_t`) as a normal parameter -- you can only pass it as a template parameter. In the case of a function template, the template parameters are typically deduced automatically by the compiler from the type you pass for that parameter, so given:

```
template <class T>
void f(T x) {}
```

The compiler will figure out that if you pass (for example) `1` as the parameter, then `T` will be `int` for this instantiation. If you pass `1.0` instead, it'll figure out that `T` is `double` for that intantiation.

If you really want to (such as wanting value converted to the type of T, instead of T being chosen as whatever type is passed) you can specify a template parameter for a function template about like you can/do for a class template. For example, `f<double>(1)` will instantiate `f` for a double, even though the value you've passed is an int. Therefore, the int will be promoted to double before being passed to the function.

Comment: I believe he's asking how to pass the type symbol itself, not an individual object of that type.